# Which ip addresses does apple use for testing iPhone applications?

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval

I'm looking at an application that is submitted for acceptance into the iOS App Store. The application contains components that pull data from private servers.

It would be useful to know which ip addresses Apple will likely use when testing the application - ie., which ip address range is likely to be the one running the test applications.

Does Apple use a predictable set/range of addresses when testing iphone applications, and, if they do, what is the range?

Comment: What will you benefit if you know that?

Comment: I've seen them request data from a number of IP addresses though all of them have come from Apple registered IP address allocations. Check the internet registries for Apple's ranges (e.g. ripe.net for Europe).

Comment: @antf common courtesy. If someone were doing me the favor of testing a system I've built, and then providing feedback, I'd feel rather rude not putting in extra effort when watching the system on my end.

Comment: If they are smart they use a vpn to some random location so you can't deliver special content for the reviewers. "People say this is a porn app! But all I see are unicorns"

Comment: @Matthias Bauch - unicorn porn app. Called it first, dibs on implementing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 9):

Both times that we submitted an app testing was performed from the 17.218.239 subnet.

Apple is assigned the 17.0.0.0/8 range

Knowing the IP address is very helpful for us as we use a third party system to authenticate (via oauth). The third party system uses a risk-based authentication system which looks at the IP address to asses "risk". If it's a new IP address then an access code is required (which is delivered via email). Getting this access code to the iOS tester is cumbersome. Knowing the IP address of the tester allows us to bypass this step and makes testing easier.